# Can RHQ Slow down system?

Tags: performance, postgresql, jboss, openfire, rhq

We have installed RHQ monitoring system http://rhq-project.org/display/RHQ/Home. From that time our program started to slow down. It happens every day at 9:20~30 AM. Can RHQ slow down system? Because our admin claims that the RHQ can not slow down the system :)

System consist of:

- Openfire 3.7.1
- JbossEAP 5.1
- Postgresql 9.0

Comment: It's unlikely the monitoring system would place any real stress on the computer, but it's not true to say it cannot slow down the computer. Every little bit of "stuff" the computer has to do is ... something it has to do. Computers aren't infinitely powerful (yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it happens every day at the same time, monitor what the machine is doing at this time. The output of "top", "vmstat" and "iotop" would probably be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Check the different metrics that are being gathered by RHQ.  One thought could be that several metrics are being gathered at exactly the same time (which happens to be 9:20) and that is causing a bit of a slow down.

Is the slow down on only one server or are you monitoring multiple servers?